# Arrow indicating cycle between two pictures using TikZ -- missing arrowheads

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm trying to draw two arrows that should indicate that a neural network cycles between two states. Following the tutorial for the Petri net, I used pgfonlayer, fit and a scope to align two networks side by side. I cannot, however, get the arrow to appear, for some reason. Here is the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node[excited] (middle)                  {-2.5};
\node[inhibited]   (west)  [left=of middle]   {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle);
\node[inhibited]   (east)  [right=of middle]  {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle);
\node[excited] (north) [above=of middle]  {0.5}
    edge node       {1}  (east)
    edge node[swap] {1}  (west)
    edge node       {-1} (middle);
\node[excited]   (south) [below=of middle]  {0.5}
    edge node        {-1} (middle)
    edge node        {1}  (west)
    edge node [swap] {1}  (east);
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\node[excited] (middle1)                  {-2.5};
\node[excited]   (west1)  [left=of middle1]   {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle1);
\node[excited]   (east1)  [right=of middle1]  {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle1);
\node[inhibited] (north1) [above=of middle1]  {0.5}
    edge node       {1}  (east1)
    edge node[swap] {1}  (west1)
    edge node       {-1} (middle1);
\node[inhibited]   (south1) [below=of middle1]  {0.5}
    edge node        {-1} (middle1)
    edge node        {1}  (west1)
    edge node [swap] {1}  (east1);
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node (n1) [fit=(west) (middle) (east) (south) (north)] {};
    \node (n2) [fit=(west1) (middle1) (east1) (south1) (north1)] {};
    \draw [shorten >=5mm,shorten <=5mm,bend left=45,<-]
        (north) to (north1);
    \draw [shorten >=5mm,shorten <=5mm,bend right=45,->]
        (south) to (south1);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the result, regardless of me having `<-` and `->` in the `\draw` command.
[image: result]

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would be better a you created a complete, compilable example, including the necessary libraries and style definitions. I get the arrow tips with a recently updated TeX Live 2013.

Comment: (Bloody typo. That should of course be '... *if* you created ...'. )

Comment: If the linked question is offtopic... This is offtopic too. Also according to the evince bug here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787927 the bug is possibly fixed with poppler 0.52.

Answer (score 4):

Would this be what you seek? You code is incompleted where this solution added some in order to get the output you posted.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,intersections,calc,fit}

\tikzset{
 excited/.style={circle,thick,draw=black,fill=blue!50,minimum size=6mm},
 inhibited/.style={circle,thick,draw,fill=none,minimum size=6mm},
 every fit/.append style=text badly centered   % to get rid of underfull bad box
 }

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\node[excited] (middle)                  {-2.5};
\node[inhibited]   (west)  [left=of middle]   {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle);
\node[inhibited]   (east)  [right=of middle]  {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle);
\node[excited] (north) [above=of middle]  {0.5}
    edge node       {1}  (east)
    edge node[swap] {1}  (west)
    edge node       {-1} (middle);
\node[excited]   (south) [below=of middle]  {0.5}
    edge node        {-1} (middle)
    edge node        {1}  (west)
    edge node [swap] {1}  (east);
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\node[excited] (middle1)                  {-2.5};
\node[excited]   (west1)  [left=of middle1]   {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle1);
\node[excited]   (east1)  [right=of middle1]  {0.5}
    edge node {-1} (middle1);
\node[inhibited] (north1) [above=of middle1]  {0.5}
    edge node       {1}  (east1)
    edge node[swap] {1}  (west1)
    edge node       {-1} (middle1);
\node[inhibited]   (south1) [below=of middle1]  {0.5}
    edge node        {-1} (middle1)
    edge node        {1}  (west1)
    edge node [swap] {1}  (east1);
\end{scope}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node (n1) [fit=(west) (middle) (east) (south) (north)] {};
    \node (n2) [fit=(west1) (middle1) (east1) (south1) (north1)] {};
    \draw [shorten >=5mm,shorten <=5mm,bend left=45,<-]
        (north) to (north1);
    \draw [shorten >=5mm,shorten <=5mm,bend right=45,->]
        (south) to (south1);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for the late reply. It seems there was never a problem to begin with -- I noticed that when my final PDF document was viewed in chrome, the arrowheads appeared. Upon closer inspection, zooming into ca. 250% in evince showed them as well. I am not sure why this happens in evince.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to put this as an answer seeing as someone else might run into the same if they are using the same PDF viewer(evince) as I was.

I noticed that when my PDF was viewed in chrome, the arrowheads appeared. In evince at 100% zoom, there were none. If I zoomed in to roughly 250%, they would appear. I am not sure why this happens, but if anyone else runs into this problem, well; it isn't really a problem.

Comment: I've also run into this problem. See this [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1133257).