# Arrowheads not showing up when drawing with tikz's automata library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, auctex

I am trying to draw a state diagram for a DFA in `LaTeX` using the `automata` library from the `tikz` package but am having trouble drawing some of the edges: Whenever the edge goes diagonally between two nodes, the arrowhead seemingly refuses to show up!

For example, this code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows}

\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm,auto]
  \node[state,initial] (q0) {$q_0$};
  \node[state] (q1) [right of=q0] {$q_1$};
  \node[state,accepting] (q2) [below of=q1] {$q_2$};
   \path[->] (q0) edge [loop above] node {a} ()
             (q0) edge node {b} (q1)
             (q1) edge node {a} (q2)
             (q1) edge [loop above] node {b} (q1)
             (q2) edge [loop right] node {a} ()
             (q2) edge node {b} (q0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

produces

[image]

which is fine except the edge between nodes q2 and q0 is lacking an arrowhead indicating that the path goes from q2 to q0.

In fact, if I adjust the position of q2 so that it is instead below q0:

```
      \node[state,accepting] (q2) [below of=q1] {$q_2$};
   -> \node[state,accepting] (q2) [below of=q0] {$q_2$};
```

now this edge has the arrowhead drawn just fine, but the edge from q1 to q2 is missing the arrowhead instead!

[image]

I am unsure if this is simply a limitation of tikz or of my editor (I am using AuCTeX in `emacs`, displaying the pdf in `evince`), or if I am simply not drawing the tikzpicture correctly.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: welcome to tex. se! in your code is missing `\begin{document}`. adding it and test your code i obtain expected result: all edges have arrowhead.

Comment: @Zarko I can verify you observation. I use Miktex, Texworks and the internal PDF-viewer. No difference using Adobe Reader.

Comment: @Zarko @Sveinung Yep, you're both right, the real solution is that I should get a better PDF reader than `evince`. I just checked out the pdf `auctex` in `xpdf` instead and arrowhead rendered perfectly. Thanks, sorry for trivial question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow indicating cycle between two pictures using TikZ -- missing arrowheads](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168553/arrow-indicating-cycle-between-two-pictures-using-tikz-missing-arrowheads)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it deals with a viewer issue.

Comment: @TeXnician: The linked question has exactly the same problem and I flagged it as off-topic. But my flag was not helpful for some reason (even if in both answers -comment of first and body of second- the problem was clearly exactly the same with the same viewer.)

Answer (score 2):

I used the below test:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt, node distance=2cm,auto]
             \draw[->](0,0)--(7,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,0);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,2);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,3);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,4);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,5.5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,6);
             \draw[->](0,0)--(7,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(6,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(5,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(4,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(3.5,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(3,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(2,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(1,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(0,7);

             \draw[->](0,0)--(-7,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,0);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,2);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,3);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,4);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,5.5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,6);
             \draw[->](0,0)--(-7,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-6,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-5,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-4,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-3.5,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-3,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-2,7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-1,7);

              \draw[->](0,0)--(-7,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,-2);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,-3);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,-4);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,-5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,-5.5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-7,-6);
             \draw[->](0,0)--(-7,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-6,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-5,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-4,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-3.5,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-3,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-2,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(-1,-7);

             \draw[->](0,0)--(7,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,-2);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,-3);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,-4);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,-5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,-5.5);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(7,-6);
             \draw[->](0,0)--(7,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(6,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(5,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(4,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(3.5,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(3,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(2,-7);
             \draw[->] (0,0)--(1,-7);
             \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
```

And the result for zoom=125% is:

[image]

But with zoom=175%:

[image]

Other tested pdf viewers works as expected. So, it is an unreleted problem with TeX-LaTeX and it is viewer specific but I think the answer is usefull to see what and when happens because evince is the default pdf viewer in many linux distributions and many latex users use linux.

Another question with the same issue is this one :[Arrow indicating cycle between two pictures using TikZ -- missing arrowheads](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168553/arrow-indicating-cycle-between-two-pictures-using-tikz-missing-arrowheads/169429)

So the current is a duplicate of the first and I will mark it as a duplicate of the earlier I mentioned.

I would suggest to change the title of the first even if we have to mark it as off-topic (the earlier) but not to delete it because many linux users will need it.

The problem that my example shows it that the arrow tip disappears for zooms less than 175% and directions close to any diagonal direction.

Off-topic:I will try to use this answer to fill a bug for evince and I will add the link below for anyone want to say that it affects him.

Comment: Bug report here : https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=787927

Comment: also manifests in Atril document viewer